# Java get Instant second day midnight time

Tags: java, date

Now I have code, which adding to current time 24 hours. I need to change it and have time of second day midnight. In my case I need to have output: `2021-11-30T00:00:00.815109800Z`.

`ZonedDateTime Date = ZonedDateTime.now(Database.ZONE_ID);`

`Date.plusSeconds(86400)).toInstant()` current output is `2021-11-30T11:05:58.815109800Z`.

I need end of today/start of tomorrow - 00:00:00.
How can I do it?

Comment: `ZonedDateTime` has methods `setHour`, `setMinute` and `setSecond` that you can use to set those fields to 0. (to be precise they return a new `ZonedDateTime` instance each, but that's beside the point here).

Comment: Why not `date.plusDays(1)` instead of `date.plusSeconds(86400)`? Also note as per the conventions it should be `date` instead of `Date` because that might be confused with one of the `Date` classes.

Comment: Please provide a minimal, reproducible example (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). It is, for example, unclear how you create your output.

Comment: You could also use `truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.DAYS)` to get time `00:00:00.000` (I assume that `00.815` portion was a typo because that's not exactly midnight :) )

Comment: @Yeti IMHO the code in the question is enough to understand what the problem is. Not all questions need a full working program.

Comment: "In my case I need to have output: 2021-11-30T00:00:00.815109800Z"  -that's not midnight, that's a fraction of a second after midnight. It's unclear to me what you're really trying to achieve.

Comment: Btw, what time do you need exactly? The end of _today_ (start of tomorrow) or the end of tomorrow? From your example it seems to be "end of today/start of tomorrow", right?

Comment: I need end of today/start of tomorrow - 00:00:00

Comment: Okay, so why have you included a non-zero sub-second part in your expected output? Is that *actually* what you want, or not?

Answer (score 4):

Well, if you want exactly midnight, then you could use `truncatedTo`:

```java
ZonedDateTime date = ZonedDateTime.parse("2021-11-29T11:31:15.815109800Z")
    .plusDays(1)
    .truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.DAYS);
```

The effect of `truncatedTo` is that it sets all fields *smaller* than the provided argument to zero. In our case we provided *days*, so the hours, minutes, seconds and fraction-of-seconds are set to 0.

But that'll also set the fraction of second to zero. Judging by the question, you want to retain the fraction-of-second. Not sure why you want that, but hey, it's *your* question.

If you really want to retain the fraction of second, then you must set the hour, minute and second to zero:

```java
ZonedDateTime date = ZonedDateTime.parse("2021-11-29T11:31:15.815109800Z")
    .plusDays(1)
    .withHour​(0)
    .withMinute(0)
    .withSecond(0);

// Or reset hour, minute and seconds at once:
//  .with(ChronoField.SECOND_OF_DAY, 0)
```

---

Now that if you are using this conversion often, you could also write a `TemporalAdjuster`, and then call the `ZonedDateTime::with(TemporalAdjuster)` method. For example:

```java
TemporalAdjuster nextDayWithFractionOfSecondAdjuster = temporal -> temporal
    .plus(1, ChronoUnit.DAYS)
    .with(ChronoField.SECOND_OF_DAY, 0);

ZonedDateTime date = ZonedDateTime.parse("2021-11-29T11:05:58.815109800Z")
    .with(nextDayWithFractionOfSecondAdjuster)
```

Comment: An impressive answer. It’s detailed and it fully exploits the options offered by java.time.

Comment: Thanks, Ole! – –